# Electromagnetic Radiation and Communication!

Tags: communication, electromagnetism, radio, telecommunications

I read that the accelerated charges create electromagnetic field/spectrum which consists of following different waves:

gamma 
X-rays
ultraviolet 
visible light
infrared
microwaves
radio waves

gamma,ultraviolet and x-rays are injurious to human so why humans are not effected by them during normal transmission of electricity as electricity is all around us. Plus only radio waves and microwaves are mostly used for communication. So how these waves are picked up from the spectrum for communication ?

Comment: Maybe post a link to the document that you read.

Comment: i do not have link. i said anything wrong ?

Comment: please make correction.

Comment: The key element is how quickly the charges are accelerated; this determines the wavelength and hence their danger to humans. This is really Physics 101, subsection Electromagnetism, not electrical engineering.

Comment: @JvO so to get a specific wave amongst them we need a specific acceleration of charges ?

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrated to physics?

Comment: @Alex there are guidelines on this site, maybe you might want to review them. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer Your question is too broad and you didn't do much research. IMO your question could easily be answered by reading several wikipedia articles. You would learn more, and the community would have more time to answer questions. If you have a specific question and you think an expert would be the best person to ask then this site is for you, it is not a site to discuss topics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because electrical engineering doesn't study accelerated particles.

Comment: all of you look at the answer below by Tom and learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humans are not dying all around due to radiation poisoning because it's hard to create electromagnetic radiation that'll actually do damage. Radio waves are pretty safe. They are something called Non-Ionising radiation, this means they won't blast apart you dna giving you cancer, radio waves just heat stuff up, but they don't work on us water people until you get into the *high power* GHz realm, regular boring old radio waves just don't pack enough punch to be much of a hazard (we don't absorb MHz range stuff well at all). It takes a lot of energy to heat water, the average microwave crams 700+ watts into a shoebox sized cavity (which contains all that energy like... well, an oven), without the enclosed box, you'd struggle to boil a cup of water.

Infrared radiation is just a fancy name for heat, and unless you've been spending too long in interstellar space, you'll be giving off your own heat, along with everything else, heat is only a problem if you barbecue yourself so I wouldn't even give IR radiation a second thought.

Now UV rays do cause problems if you get exposed to high enough doses, but seeing as you can *see* UV light to some extent, you'd know if you were being exposed to an unsafe amount (plus you'd have a burning sensation on your skin). Now a flow of electricity won't generate anything other than radio waves (and heat) on it's own, it needs help to produce other forms of radiation. When welding for example, the arc burns so hot that it rips electrons from air molecules. This gets the electrons all exited as they fly around the place, when they eventually find their way back to lonely air molecules, they give out a burst of UV light (among other pretty colours) as they calm down and get settled in their new home. Believe it or not, this is is what goes on in fluorescent lamps and neon signs (some gasses produce more UV than others)

Now see, X-rays are quite dangerous as they *are* a form of ionising radiation, so they will blast apart dna and other things. Catch is, they're quite hard to make. To make some X-rays that would actually be hazardous (standing a few meters away would block most of the low energy x-rays), is quite hard. To make hazardous x-rays you have to first get a bunch of electrons to leave their atomic homes and get them floating free AND as a focused beam (easier said than done), then you have to accelerate them to a few % light speed, you're going to need some high voltage source of at least 50'000V for this. Then you have to fire this high energy electron beam at something really dense, tungsten works well. When the electrons come screaming to a half as they blast into the tungsten, they give off X-rays as they dissipate their kinetic energy. All this has to be done under high vacuum of course or the electrons will spread out and come to a gradual stop as they bounce off the light air molecules. Seeing as how these conditions don't present themselves often outside a lab, you've not got much to worry about here either.

And if you want gamma rays, well it's even harder, you already had to hit a few percent light speed in a high vacuum under high voltage to get x-rays, you'll need much more energy to produce gamma rays, so unless you are splitting atoms, you should be pretty safe.

Just because all of these forms of radiation are electromagnetic, does not mean a flow of electricity will produce them. Sound is just a pressure wave, so is the shock wave from a bomb blast, but one is far harder to produce. You won't be blowing yourself across the room with your stereo system no matter how high you crank the volume. So relax, those power lines in the distance won't be irradiating you anytime soon.

Comment: great @Tom you answered my question very well when many others were just cursing me for asking that. lol thank you.

Comment: There's no such thing as a stupid question, only a stupid answer

Comment: yes no question is stupid :)

Comment: you mean to say that all these different type of electromagnetic waves are created with different techniques and when one of them is created then a "help" is needed to cause the other type ?

Comment: sorry to bother you again @Tom

Comment: Making IR (heat) and radio waves is pretty easy, almost anything with a changing voltage that isn't superconducting (i.e. no power loss) will produce some radio waves and heat. Generating microwaves requires a bit of effort, but really you just need a fast switch. All the others require more than *just* a flow of electricity. UV can be produced with special LEDs, some lasers, striking an arc in most gasses (eg. lightning, welding, fluoro tubes, photo flashes) and some chemical reactions (burning thermite produces UV I think).

Comment: The reason UV, x-rays and especially gamma rays are hard to produce is because thay have very high photon energy, each photon of light has energy, the more energy per photon the harder it is to make but the more destructive it is. UV light has a few eV of energy (an electron gains one eV of kinetic energy by being accelerated by a potential difference of one volt, so not that much energy).

Comment: X-rays are into the keV, with most medical systems being 50-100keV in order to actually penetrate through a person. There's no strict lower limit for gamma rays (defined as atomic energy) but they can range from a few keV (x-rays, just from an atom rather than an xray tube) up to anything (no upper limit either), but nuclear gamma rays are often in the MeV range. for comparison, a microwave oven 'photon' has an energy of only 10ueV (or about 1 trillionth the energy)

Comment: It's theoretically possible to build an antenna that would broadcast light or even xray or gamma rays (they are all electromagnetic waves afterall), but the technology doesn't exist yet. Building antennas that work at IR frequencies has recently been possible, but they were receive only (no switch in existence can go fast enough to create oscillations in the IR range, that would require a speed of several tens of terahertz, people are struggling to get past 1THz). UV and higher require even higher frequencies, it's possible to create any electromagnetic radiation the same way, just real hard

Comment: +1 for the great answer (both information and style) well done :)

Comment: Just doing my civit duty. Nobody really wants a 3 hour academic answer, *especially* when there's a simple 5 minute explanation

Answer (score 0):

The crucial quantity that decides whether electromagnetic radiation damages biological tissue is the energy per photon, not the total power of the radiation.

If the energy per photon is higher than the energy needed to break chemical bonds it is biologically harmful. That energy is in the order of several eV (electron-volts, see e.g. [Wikipedia "Bond-dissociation energy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond-dissociation_energy)).

There is a well known relation between energy per photon and wavelength or frequncy of the radiation:

\$E = h\nu\ = \frac{h c}{\lambda} \$

(\$E\$=energy per photon, h = Planck constant, \$\nu\$=frequency, \$c\$= speed of light, \$\lambda\$= wavelength of radiation)

If you plug in the values you get the result that EM radiation of frequency above visibly light (UV, X-ray, gamma ray) starts to become harmful.

Radiation used for radio communication is well below that limit.

This so far relates to the most dangerous damaging mechanism: breaking chemical bonds.

Another mechanism is by exciting (rotating, oscillating) molecules which results in heating the tissue. That happens at much lower frequencies (mircowave or even as low frequencies as VHF). It is, however, much less dangerous because higher power is needed (several 100W at close distance) to cause damage and it doesn't accumulate, i.e. if the material doesn't get too hot and can cools down again the effect is reversible (in contrast to when chemical bonds are broken).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the power contents of the wave (signal) and operating frequency and exposure yes there is some degree of interaction between human tissues and those waves. The question is: how much interaction and what kind of damage would that cause?

The answer is: it all depends of the exposure and intensity (power contents) to those waves. The higher the power dose and more exposure the more damage it may cause to human.

Also, radio waves go through what is called "Modulation and Coding" .. Modulation can be thought of as a bus that carries human from point A to point B - here people are like Data and the bus is the RF energy. Also Coding is a method of implementing function within the radio signal, for example Radio Frequency (RF) is modified in certain way to carry signal to turn ON the light (ON signal) and can also be modified to carry signal to turn OFF the light (OFF signal) - so the ON and OFF commands contained within the RF wave are codes embedded within the RF signal.

There are more ways of establishing communication between different points (A, B, C, and so on...) Addressing those RF signals can guide them to certain recipients only (addressable RF signaling).

Comment: so it means that the radio waves can also be dangerous if they have more power and normal electricity do not cause that much powerful x-rays and gamma rays which are harmful ?

Comment: Yes for example being close to Radar antenna will impose more danger than being far, same applies to being close to Cell Phone Towers. So stay as far as you can from those large Radar systems and Tower Antennas. On the other hands if you are close to cables carrying DC current it wont be as dangerous though.

Comment: thank you. few more minutes please. normal electricity and transmission lines do cause x-rays and gamma rays ? are they not so powerful to cause damage ?

Comment: The reason is that AC tends to jump off the wires and travel because it changes direction. The AC current fluctuation is what causes this energy to jump off those wires and cables. Also this is why the power transmission lines are usually kept high on poles in the roads. Also note that those cables on street poles are kept separate otherwise they will interfere with one another, because those lines carry thousands of volts they will penetrate human body as well - however the damage depends on how long you stay close to them.

Comment: yes thats because of the electromagnetic induction. but do they produce x-rays and gamma rays also which are not harmful ?